# What is the best practice when return different types(object) by condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a function to validate for input arguments. But I'm not sure it's the best practice to use.

I have a function that validates like this,

```js
const isValidStudyId = (id) => {
  if (validator.isUUID(id) === false || isValidArguments([id]) !== true) {
    console.log(`${id} is invalid Study Id`);
    return { valid: false, message: `${id} is invalid id!` };
  }
  return true;
}
```

And use this like this,

```js
  const isValidId = utils.isValidStudyId(studyId)
  if (isValidId !== true) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: isValidId.message
    });
    return;
  }
```

And I don't like the way it check validity like

```
if (isValidId !== true)
```

this way. Because it's returning sometimes boolean, sometimes an object. Could you suggest other ways to do? I'm not very familiar with the javascript, and I wanna learn more about what is the best practice in this sort of situation.

Comment: As per your example, I think the best thing is to throw an error saying ``${id} is invalid id`` and wrap the call to ``isValidStudyId`` in a try-catch in other codes.

Comment: You should `return { valid: true };` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `validateStudyId` instead that returns a message why it's invalid if it's invalid, otherwise returns a falsy value.

```
const validateStudyId = (id) => {
  if (validator.isUUID(id) === false || isValidArguments([id]) !== true) {
    const message = `${id} is invalid Study Id`;
    console.log(message);
    return {
      valid: false,
      message
    };
  } // else undefined
}
```

and then you can just test it like it's boolean and even chain several such checks together in a way that stops at the first truthy response, like this:

```
const o = validateStudyId(id) || validateOtherThing() || validateThirdThing();
if (o) {
  res.status(400).send(o); // no need to create a new object
}
```

Comment: Yea, that make sense. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

### The Normal Way

If you're referring solely to what structure you *should* use, perhaps returning something like `{valid: true}` and check the valid property, as the message property is only checked when `valid` is `false`, it's not necessary to set one when `valid` is `true`, unless you want to.

---

### The Weird *(and maybe ever so slightly nonstandard)* Way

Another option would be to use something like [callback functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp) to structure your flow differently.

```js
// 'next' is a function that takes two arguments (error, message)
const checkStudyID = (id, next) => {
    // '=== false' is somewhat redundant if these checks always return booleans
    if(!validator.isUUID(id) || !isValidArguments([id])) {
        console.log(`${id} is an invalid Study ID`);
        return next(true, `${id} is invalid id!`);
    }
    next(false);
}

// --- USAGE ---
utils.checkStudyId(studyId, (err, msg) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send({message: msg});
});
```

Comment: A callback function is a very unusual solution to this. Especially the format that you used, which indicates an asynchronous callback but isn't.

Comment: @Bergi Perhaps it's just me being weird then. Either way, the latter half of my answer will likely suffice for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Indeed, I like that part much better than the first :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'll make an edit now to swap their order around. Thanks for the insight!